# An inequality related $\|f\|_3\|g\|_3^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

What is the name of the following inequality?
$$\int |f| |g|^2 dx\leq C\|f\|_3\|g\|_3^2\tag{1}$$

We encounted it in the proof of the global regularity for the viscous 2D Boussinesq equations in ref.1
(Jiahong Wu, The 2D Incompressible Boussinesq Equations, Peking University Summer School Lecture Notes (2012))

Comment: Just a special case of Holder's inequality. In fact, we can take $C=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known generalization of Holder's inequality: provided $\sum 1/p_i = 1$ (where $p_i > 1$) and $f_i \in L^{p_i}(\Omega)$ for each $i$, then
$$
\left\| \prod_i f_i \right\|_{1,\Omega} \le \prod_i \left\| f_i \right\|_{p_i,\Omega}
$$
in the sense of the usual $p$-norms:
$$
\|f\|_{p,\Omega} := \left( \int_\Omega |f|^p \right)^{1/p}
$$

Holder's inequality is the case of two functions.

Your result arises for three functions, taking $f_1 = f$ and $f_2=f_3=g$ and $p_1=p_2=p_3=3$.

---

Alternatively, just apply Holder's inequality in the usual form: given $p,q \in [1,\infty]$ with $1/p+1/q=1$ and $f \in L^p(\Omega), g \in L^q(\Omega)$, then
$$
\|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q
$$
Apply this with $p=3$, $q=3/2$, and replace $g$ with $g^2$. Note that
$$
\|g^2\|_{3/2} = \left( \int_\Omega \left(|g|^2\right)^{3/2} \right)^{2/3}
= \left[ \left( \int_\Omega |g|^3 \right)^{1/3} \right]^2
= \|g\|_3^2
$$

Comment: No need for generalized Holder's inequality. Very simple application of Holder with conjugate exponents $3$ and $3/2$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I agree with you that your first comment solved my puzzle. Since you did not write a formal answer, I will accept Prince's answer. For someone like me not in math major, we just do not know where to look for answer. Prince's detailed generalization is also very helpful to me.